# Fixed point for probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Well, I have the following question:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measurable space, then we can define a prob. measure in the same space by defining $P(A)=\int_A f d\mu$, with $\int f d\mu=1$.

Let $P^{(k)}(A)=\int_A f dP^{(k-1)}$ with $P^{(0)}(A)=\int_A f d\mu$. When can we be sure this recursion to be well defined, and to exist a fixed point?

Comment: Did you start by computing the density of $P^{(k)}$ with respect to $\mu$?

Comment: @Did No, but now that you're asking, it seems my question doesn't make much sense...

Comment: What do you mean? That the limit is rarely a probability measure? Sure, but this does not fail to make sense, does it?

Comment: @Did I'm learning this, and sometimes this community can sometimes be a bit daunting to the less 'mathematically gifted'. So, given how I'm conscientious of it, I usually try not to dwell too much on certain questions, since I'm pretty sure I won't understand or end up bothering a bit  the replier... lol 

In my question, $\mu$ can be any measure. Well, since I'm learning this, could you give me a pointer as to how to calculate the density. Thanks Did for your help. ;)

Comment: Well, you know the density of $P^{(k)}$ with respect to $P^{(k-1)}$ hence you should be able to write down the density of $P^{(k)}$ with respect to $\mu$ in terms of the density of $P^{(k-1)}$ with respect to $\mu$, and then to deduce  the density of $P^{(k)}$ with respect to $\mu$ for every $k$.

Comment: @Did, I've just read a theorem that allows me to do that, so

$P^{(k)}(A)=\int_A f^{k+1}(\omega)d\mu(\omega)$.

So, if f has a pointwise limit function that is integrable, then the integral could exist. Is this sufficient?

Comment: "if f has a pointwise limit function" Actually you are interested in the pointwise limit of $f^k$. What is this limit? (It is quite degenerate.)

Comment: @Did, I see... It's zero if $f(x) \in ]-1,1[$, $=1$ if $f(x)=1$, and diverges elsewhere... Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is always well-defined, just since your defined it well. Regarding fixpoint, you even don't have to compute the limits. Let's call your operator $A$, that is $A\nu = \int f\;\mathrm d\nu$. So you need to find $\nu$ such that $\nu = A\nu$. Note that $A\nu \ll \nu$, hence $g = \frac{\mathrm d A\nu}{\mathrm d\nu}$ is always defined, and for $\nu$ to be a fixpoint we must have $g = 1$ $\nu$-a.e. Clearly, by construction $f = g$ $\nu$-a.e., hence fixpoints are given by
$$
  F(A) = \{\nu: f = 1 \;\nu\text{-a.e.}\}
$$